# Broken CSS in Sphinx build on readthedocs.org

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

My project builds its documentation on readthedocs.org using Sphinx.

I notice that something that used to work is now broken: there is `list-style: none` applied to the lists, when there shouldn't be: https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Perhaps something changed in the `sphinx_rtd_theme`?

But when I build it locally, using make, everything looks like it should.

The makefile is here: https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/blob/master/docs/Makefile

Comment: Check the change log: https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html. That said, check the version number of the style sheet in question: https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/css/theme.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it worked, but I solved it by setting the following in my requirements.txt:

```
sphinx_rtd_theme>=1.2
```

For some reason, setting it to <2.0.0 as they recommend didn't work.